# Timeout Exception

Tags: c#, exception, timeout

my code looks somewhat like this:

```
    try
    {
        return myClass.doSomethind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Result emptyResult = new Result();
        return emptyResult;
    }
```

myClass is one of 15 inherited classes from myClassBase.
So far the exception handling works. If in myClass.doSomething() an exception is thrown it ends up in the catch block.
Now I want to add something like a Timeout Exception, which is thrown, when myClass.doSomething() takes to long.
The following code doesn't work, since the thrown exception is not propagated to the try block.

```
    try
    {
        System.Timers.Timer TimeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); 
        TimeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;
        TimeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutErrorEventHandler;
        TimeoutTimer.Enabled = true;
        return myClass.doSomethind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Result emptyResult = new Result();
        return emptyResult;
    }

static void TimeoutErrorEventHandler(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("Timeout")
}
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
try
{
    System.Timers.Timer TimeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); 
    TimeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;
    TimeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutErrorEventHandler;
    TimeoutTimer.Enabled = true;
    Task<Result> doSomethingTask = Task.Run (() => myClass.doSomethind());
    if (doSomethingTask.Wait(10000) 
    {
       return doSomethingTask.Result;  
    }
    else 
    {
        Result emptyResult = new Result();
        return emptyResult;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Result emptyResult = new Result();
    return emptyResult;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I've tried this but `doSoemthing()` will be interrupted but not canceled. After `return emptyResult` it continues on `doSomething()`.

Comment: Well, then you need to implement doSomething to support cancellation using a CancellationToken. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-8.0